# Using struct to create a multi-dimming LED system

Tags: list, struct, arduino

I tried to have a random fading pattern on several leds and it leads to flickering because it cannot recognise which led are already on use.

I am in the process of creating a simple lamp that show some light patterns using 6 led and an arduino uno. The goal is that depending on some inputs and a bit of randomisation, the patterns will change. For instance, only 2 lights at the same time but fading up and down randomly on all 6 led. Or 4 lights fading up and down randomly on the 6 leds.

I decided to create a struct that would be a light pattern named a particle, and this particle have a variable named led_position that shows which led it is on at a certain moment. The particle can change its position to light up an other led.

I have tried to add a data field for busy, as you can see and to update the list of available led ( the one without a busy process on it) to no avail.

'''Main code '''' -edited after bartek's comment.

```
#include "MyTypes.h"

int led0 = 3;    // the PWM pin the LED is attached to
int led1 = 5; 
int led2 = 6; 
int led3 = 9; 
int led4 = 10; 
int led5 = 11; 



//int led;
int brightness;
int fadeAmount;


// Definition of the different particles
particle_type particle[]={
  { 0,led0,0, 2,   false },  
  { 1,led1,50, 2,   false },  
  { 2,led2,100,  2,   false },  
  { 3,led3,80,  2,   false },
  { 4,led4,30,  2,   false},
  { 5,led5,70,  2,   false},
};

led_type led[]={
  { 3,false },  
  { 5,false },  
  { 6,false },  
  { 9,false },
  { 10,false },
  { 11,false },
};



//initiation of the particles

void initiate_particle(particle_type& particle_example,led_type led[]){



 //take a random led from list of led  
  int number=random(6);
  Serial.println(number);
  led[number];
  if (led[number].busy == false){ //if led non-occupied
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
      if (led[i].led_position==particle_example.led_position){
      led[i].busy=false;
      Serial.println("success");
      Serial.println(led[i].led_position);
      }
    }
    particle_example.led_position=led[number].led_position;
    Serial.println(particle_example.led_position);
    led[number].busy = true ;//take this led as output
    } 

  else{
//  initiate_particle( particle_example,led);
}

  particle_example.reset = false; //reset turned off 
  delay(30);

}

void update_light(particle_type& particle_example,led_type led[]){ //updating led brightness

analogWrite(particle_example.led_position, particle_example.brightness);  //updating led brightness
  if (particle_example.brightness >=  160) {
    particle_example.fadeAmount = -particle_example.fadeAmount;

  }

  if (particle_example.brightness <=  160 && particle_example.brightness >=  100 ) {
    particle_example.brightness = particle_example.brightness + 2*particle_example.fadeAmount;

  }

  if (particle_example.brightness >= 50 && particle_example.brightness <=  100){ 
      particle_example.brightness = particle_example.brightness + particle_example.fadeAmount;

  }

  if (particle_example.brightness >= 0 && particle_example.brightness <=  50){ 
      particle_example.brightness = particle_example.brightness + 0.5*particle_example.fadeAmount;

  }

  if (particle_example.brightness <= 0){
    particle_example.reset= true;
    particle_example.brightness =0;
    int number = particle_example.led_position;
    particle_example.fadeAmount = -particle_example.fadeAmount;
  }



}

void activate_particle(particle_type& particle_example,led_type led[]){ //function to keep led activated

  if (particle_example.reset==true){ //if led not initiated or has finished its dimming down
    initiate_particle(particle_example, led); //initiate it again
  ;}

  else {
   update_light(particle_example,led); //update its brightness
  }
}

void setup() { //create led outputs
  pinMode(led0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led5, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600); //serial for debug

}



void loop() {

  activate_particle(particle[0],led);
  activate_particle(particle[1],led);
  activate_particle(particle[2],led);
//  activate_particle(particle[3],led);
//  activate_particle(particle[4],led);
//  activate_particle(particle[5],led);
//  

 delay(10); // 20-17-15-12-10-7-2

}
```

'''Mytypes.h''''

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int led_position;
    int brightness;
    int fadeAmount;
    bool reset;
} particle_type;

typedef struct {
    int led_position;
    bool busy;
} led_type;
```

The code runs and the particles go from led to led but they sometime merge into a single one and this makes the LED flickers.
The problems are almost non-existent when 1 to 3 particles are activated but become a problem starting at 4 up to 6.
How can I make sure that they don't 'take' the same led to output.
On top of that it seems that some leds are "discarded". How can I make sure that they stay active.

Comment: Don't know if this could be the solution, but this code is dangerous: `if (particle_example.brightness <= 0)` : your brightness is signed, but the analogWrite expect an unsigned value. So, if you send -1, the led will probably go from 0 to MAX. And you never set it to 0 if it is <0. You should do it. Just to be sure to have a positive number.

Comment: Your port numbers don't correspond to the `led` array values. Was that intentional?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, not sure what you mean by port number. They seem the same to me in a diffferent order. You are right that I should clean it.

Comment: Found most of the answer on the arduino stack exchange:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/68896/multi-dimming-led-figuring-out-which-led-is-available-for-dimming